# Why is my HTML replacement assignation not working?

Tags: jquery, html, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-webpages

When a selection is made, I want to replace the current content with other content. I am trying to replace (for now), a change from a previous selection to "Tom Sawyer will be added later" when "Tom Sawyer" is selected from the drop down. But it is not working - the existing HTML (HuckFinn) remains in the div. Here is the pertinent code:

```
$('#fictionDropDown').change(function () {
    configLoading();
    var sel = this.value;
    if ((sel == "HuckFinn") && (currentFictionSelection != "HuckFinn")) {
        $('#FictionContent').load('Content/HuckFinn.html');
        currentFictionSelection = "HuckFinn";
    }
    else if ((sel == "TomSawyer") && (currentFictionSelection != "TomSawyer")) {
        $("#FictionContent").empty();
        $('#FictionContent').html('Tom Sawyer will be added later');
        currentFictionSelection = "TomSawyer";
    }
```

...and HTML:

```
<div id="tabs" class="content-wrapper">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tab-Fiction">Fiction</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab-Nonfiction">Nonfiction</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab-MiscTwain">Miscellaneous</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab-Media">Media</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tab-Fiction">
        <select id="fictionDropDown">
            <option value="HuckFinn">Huck Finn</option>
            <option value="TomSawyer">Tom Sawyer</option>
            <option value="tPatP">Prince and the Pauper</option>
            <option value="ConnYank">Connecticut Yankee</option>
            <option value="Gilded">The Gilded Age</option>
            <option value="Puddnhead">Pudd'nhead Wilson</option>
            <option value="ShortStories">Short Stories</option>
        </select>
        <div id="FictionContent" class="clearfix">Content in Fiction tab</div>
    </div>
```

It would help if there were a way to debug this code. I've got breakpoints in the code, but none of them are hit.

Anyway, why does emptying the html and then setting it to "Tom Sawyer will be added later" not work?

Comment: Something else is causing the bug. I copied what you have here (without configLoading(), and currentFictionSelection) and it worked just fine for me. The issue is not with empty() or html(), I think it might have to do with currentFictionSelection. Do you have Firebug (or something like it) to check the JS console when you select "Tom Sawyer"? Also... why use currentFictionSelection? The change function should only run when a user selects a different option.

Comment: It's working fine for me here: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/14er6r6b/) Although I have to remove `configLoadin()` as it doesn't exist in the example and define `currentFictionSelection`. I assume it's normally defined earlier in the code?

Comment: You have to define `var currentFictionSelection = '';` above the change function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initialize currentFictionSelection with a value and now everything works fine:

```
var currentFictionSelection = 'somevalue';

$('#fictionDropDown').change(function () {
    //configLoading();
    var sel = this.value;
    if ((sel == "HuckFinn") && (currentFictionSelection != "HuckFinn")) {
        alert('foo');
        $('#FictionContent').load('Content/HuckFinn.html');
        currentFictionSelection = "HuckFinn";
    } else if ((sel == "TomSawyer") && (currentFictionSelection != "TomSawyer")) {
        alert('bar');
        $("#FictionContent").empty();
        $('#FictionContent').html('Tom Sawyer will be added later');
        currentFictionSelection = "TomSawyer";
    }
});
```

Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/BenjaminRay/u8rz59Lm/